Remaps to move across windows do not work when in netrw window
Can someone explain why remaps to navigate across windows like nmap <C-h> <C-w>h does not work when in the netrw window? Is there any reason why? Is there a setting to enable them?

The reason is that the netrw buffer defines a buffer mapping for <C-h>.
The solution is to override that buffer mapping:
autocmd! FileType netrw nnoremap <buffer> <C-h> <C-w>h

An alternative is to create a ~/vimfiles/ftplugin/netrw.vim with the following content:
nnoremap <buffer> <C-h> <C-w>h

For earlier version of Vim the buffer mapping were reset every time the netrw view were visited. In such case you have to do:
autocmd WinEnter * if &ft=='netrw' | nnoremap <buffer><C-h> <C-w>h | endif


It would be nice if you also mentioned ftplugins for things like this.

I added the remaps into a new file called netrw.vim under ~/.vim/after/plugin, but it does not work. Indeed, I also tried the autocmds in the main vimrc file, also not working. EDIT: I forgot the <buffer> argument. Now seems to be working.

Last somewhat related question: why instead the remap nmap  <A-h> <C-w>2< does not work at all, even in normal buffers?
I even tried changing to nmap  <A-h> <C-w>2<S-,>, also not working.

Maybe you should post another question about that to not confuse future readers. Did you tried  instead of ? What is the operating system that you are using (Linux, Windows, macOS)?

@VivianDeSmedt strangely enough, your solution works in my target env (it's a cluster), but not on my local machine. The only difference in versioning is: local vim --version prints VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled May 03 2024 02:37:51), remote VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Feb 09 2023 00:00:00). Might that be the cause?

I'll try to reproduce the behavior. I would be interested to have the result of the :version command on both environment (it gives the patch version of Vim).

Thanks @VivianDeSmedt . Here is the command output: Included patches: 1-579, 1969, 580-1848, 4975, 5016, 5023, 5072, 2068, 1849-1854, 1857, 1855-1857, 1331, 1858, 1858-1859, 1873, 1860-1969, 1992, 1970-1992, 2010, 1993-2068, 2106, 2069-2106, 2108, 2107-2109, 2109-3995, 4563, 4646, 4774, 4895, 4899, 4901, 4919, 213, 1840, 1846-1847, 2110-2112, 2121

I believe I can reproduce your problem. It seems that on version 8.2.2121 the buffer mapping are reset every time the focus is moved to the netrw window. For that version you could do: autocmd WinEnter * if &ft=='netrw' | nnoremap <buffer><C-h> <C-w>h | endif
